# If most of the glaciers melted suddenly how long before humans could begin resettling and advancing?

Tags: climate, post-apocalypse, space-colonization

Climate change research has shown that the Greenland/Arctic ice cap is melting at an even higher rate than the Antarctic ice cap and since most of human civilization is at the equator or above the melting would affect all major cities around the globe. I am writing a story about a group that stays in a low-orbit space station until the waters have receded and most humans have died off from the inevitable starvation and disease. They plan to resettle the planet when it has been "cleansed". How long would they need to stay in space before it would be safe to return to Earth?

Comment: As has been mentioned elsewhere, post-climate-change Earth would still be FAR more hospitable than anywhere else in the solar system.

Comment: *"Melting would affect all major cities around the globe":* There is not enough ice on Earth to raise the sea level more than about 100 meters; which means that the sea cannot come anywhere near cities such as Moscow, Kiev, Bangalore, Hyderabad, New Delhi, Islamabad, Chicago, Madrid, Milan, Turin, Prague, Vienna, etc. In fact, the only large and important flooded areas in Europe will be the Netherlands and Denmark, in the USA Florida and a low-lying strip on the east coast, in India the Ganges Plain, in Russia a vast area north of the Caspian (which will reconnect with the ocean).

Comment: See the interactive [flood map](https://www.floodmap.net) of the world.

Comment: There is a problem with staying in a "low-orbit space station." Such low-orbits decay and the station is likely to fall out of the sky before these people want to return to earth. Notice that the Hubble telescope is at risk after not that many years.

Comment: The USGS is even more pessimistic than @AlexP. They think it would only raise sea levels [70 meters](https://www.usgs.gov/faqs/how-would-sea-level-change-if-all-glaciers-melted). In the U.S. that would take out Florida, most of the East Coast, the Mississippi Delta, San Francisco and Los Angeles - but that's only a problem depending on who you ask. It would get a big chunk of England but very little of Scotland. I'd love to hear who wins that debate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sea level rise you describe would **not** be a problem for mankind as a whole if it wasn't for the supply chain disruption, starvation, refugee movements, and war. Sure, a lot of places would be under water, including some that are important to technological civilization as we know it. But Earth is big, there is plenty of land 100m or even 500m above sea level.

So it all comes down to the people. In a remotely realistic world, there should be plenty of "pockets" of survivors with technology at least at the 1900s or 1930s level -- sewage systems, power grids, steel furnaces, oil refineries. And tanks with nasty cannon. (Assuming that anything with a microchip in it cannot be replaced, and that transistor or vacuum tube computers take too long to re-invent.) They will retain the knowledge that there are people in a space station overhead who did (could?) not help much. How much did the last launches to the station cost the "dirtsiders" in resources? Do they bear a grudge?

So it might never be safe, or they wait until the new power structures settle down and strike a deal with one power.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  my story doesn't reveal the space station until they actually come back. You are right my story is all about people. The group responsible has nothing to do with government and the current state of the world has governments fighting with each other instead of looking up. Your answer was the most helpful and you acknowledged that it is not just the water level rise, the problem will be lack of resources for all those climate refugees and lots will die. I was figuring within 100 years they could return. Pockets of survivors are expected as is some tech.

Comment: The whole point of my story is that this is a way to get a "do over" instead of having to change our fossil-fuel-loving ways and suffer through the slow catastrophe. They cause it to happen and sit safely in the space ship until all the bad stuff passes then they return and start over on a less populated planet. Because it is flooding and not nuclear they would not have to stay off the surface very long, possibly return within one lifetime.